# HTML element "top" style being set generated random number but not moving to the position in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a project and remaking snake. The code is all supposed to set the position of the apple to a random number and it logs it as doing so, but the apple stays in the same place. The position type is "relative" so it stays within a box. This is my first time using HTML and Javascript together. The code just doesn't work (no errors or warnings). The random number generation code is as follows:

```
function rand(min, max, step) {
    var delta,
        range,
        rand;
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        max = min;
        min = 0;
    }
    if (!step) {
        step = 1;
    }
    delta = max - min;
    range = delta / step;
    rand = Math.random();
    rand *= range;
    rand = Math.floor(rand);
    rand *= step;
    rand += min;
    return parseInt(rand);
}
```

The code for setting the "apples" position (in js):

```
function generateApple() {
    let y = parseInt(rand(-15, 470, 15))
    apple.style.top = y
    console.log(apple.style.top)
}
```

It does successfully print the new location but doesn't move the "apple" HTML object to the position. I have the initial position set to 15 in **style.left** and 15 in **style.top**. The CSS for the apple is as follows:

```
.apple {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px;
}
```

The code that sets the position as relative when the window loads is as follows

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    snake.style.position = 'relative';
    apple.style.position = 'relative'
    snake.style.left = 105;
    snake.style.top = 105;
    apple.style.top = 15;
    apple.style.left = 15;
    if (highScore == null) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('high_score', 0)
    }
});
```

The full code is on this website: https://passionproject.on.fleek.co

Comment: "The position type is relative so it stays within a box." Well, the code you posted has no `position: relative`.

Comment: There, I fixed that. That's all the important code for the apple.

Answer (score 0):

Window `load` event is fired after the JavaScript that is positioning the apple has been run. If you put could breakpoints in your code, you will see that first it moves the apple into the right position and then the `load` event listener fires.

Since your JS is at the bottom of the page, the simplest fix really is to not use `load` event listener and just do it immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly ordered it. The code to position it is well after the load event.